# Informed badge for Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, meta, badge-request, tour, informed-badge

In Stack Overflow the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge is awarded for reading the entire *about* page.
Why is the informed badge not awarded on Meta Stack Overflow?
We have an *about* page [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) too.

Comment: Perhaps by virtue of _being_ on Meta, we consider one informed?

Comment: Oh. And the meta about page is not really the same as the non-meta about page - it is the old and inferior kind.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [informed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed) visible, but no one have been awarded it. I tried to be the first, but without any luck.

[image]

Maybe it's a bug and not a feature?!

Comment: The badges are still displayed on all sites even if they're impossible to get, for example Precognitive is listed here and on some other sites that existed before Area51 came about.

Comment: @peterj Thanks. I didn't know that

Comment: The Beta badge is visible too, but hard to get on MSO since it has never been in Beta.

Comment: @Votetoclose Done! ;)