# Informed badge not visible on my profile

Tags: support, bug

I have gone through the entire about page for meta.stackexchange.com site thoroughly but I can still find no Informed badge awarded in my profile; why is that so? Is it some kind of technical error on the website?

Comment: This has already been asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231035/informed-badge-on-meta) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188544/informed-badge-for-meta) but there is no official answer yet (other than in comments)