# Why did I get a welcome message informing me I'd get a badge for taking the tour, if that badge is not active?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When I signed up I received a welcome message *specifically* indicating I should take the tour to earn my first badge:

[image: Welcome message]

Clicking the message takes me directly to the [meta site's tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour).

**However**, as [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188544/informed-badge-for-meta-stack-overflow)  [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231035/informed-badge-on-meta), the 'Informed' badge is not active here on meta.

Shouldn't the wording of the welcome message be altered if a user signs up on a site which does not use this badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The badge will be enabled on meta with the next build.

It was originally held back because we didn't have the updated /tour page here, but now that it's live and behaving largely like the tours on other sites, there's no need to prevent the badge from being easily achievable.